# Tagging or marking a video / audio using HTML5

Tags: html

Is there a way to tag or mark a video / audio at a particular location using HTML5 during playback? It could be by right clicking on the seek bar while it's being played or something else.

I have something like YouTube's "copy video URL at current time" feature in mind. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can seek to a particular time:

```
document.getElementById('videoID').addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
  this.currentTime = 50;
}, false);
```

Also, look at http://www.annodex.net/~silvia/itext/mediafrag.html#t=40